# How to stretch property not working on images react native?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native, flexbox

I have created a card and the parent component i.e card is a flex. So after using alginSelf: 'stretch'

Code:

```
<View style={styles.card}>
    <Image source={require('./Images/facility/facility.png')} style={styles.imgFacility}></Image>
    <TouchableHighlight>
        <Text style={styles.title}>Barasti /</Text>
    </TouchableHighlight>
</View>
```

CSS:

```
card: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingLeft: 16,
    paddingRight: 16
},
imgFacility: {
    height: 200,
    alignSelf: 'stretch'
},
title: {
    color: '#ff3385'
}
```

Above code `alginSelf: 'stretch'` is not working why so ? What could be the reason ?

See screenshot:

[image]

Comment: try display:block

Comment: @lsa4299 I am using react native display is not there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your image to be full width,change your imgFacility style like this:

```
imgFacility:{
width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
height: 200,
alignSelf: 'center'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`alignSelf:'stretch` doesn't work in above case because there should be a block element to stretch.

So below code works perfectly:

```
imgFacility: {
    height: 200,
    width: '100%'
}
```